# Mongoose pre findOneAndUpdate hook issues

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to update counts on a pre hook. The issue is that for some unknown reason the `findOneAndUpdate` hook doesn't have access to the document, as far as I can tell.

I would like to do this:

```
source.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
  console.log('------------->>>>>> findOneAndUpdate: ');
  this.objects = this.objects || [];
  this.people = this.people || [];
  this.events = this.events || [];

  this.objectCount = this.objects.length;
  this.peopleCount = this.people.length;
  this.eventCount = this.events.length;

  next();
});
```

But for some reason the `this` in the hook isn't the document, its a Query object which seems about useless.

What am I missing? *How do I use a pre hook to update counts on a findOneAndUpdate?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) states:

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but important way: in document middleware, `this` refers to the document being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have a reference to the document being updated, so `this` refers to the **query** object rather than the document being updated.

An update action generally updates a document that only exists in the database (it tells the MongoDB server: *"find document X and set property X to value Z"*), so the full document isn't available to Mongoose and, hence, you can't update the counts (which requires access to at least the arrays whose length you want to determine).

As an aside: why do you need separate `*Count` properties in your schema anyway? If you want to query for arrays matching a certain size, you can use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator on the arrays directly.

If you really do need the count properties, then for each update, you need to track the number of changes you made to each of the arrays (in terms of the number of items added/deleted) and use the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to adjust the counts.

Comment: The counts are there so I can return the full list of items with `find` and exclude the arrays as I don't want the details when I return the full list. So how do I update the counts automatically? To me a pre hook without access to the document is rather pointless.

Comment: @Justin808 if you want to return array sizes, consider using [an aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/). If you want to update the counts, you need to first retrieve the full document from the database, update the values, update the counts (or use a _document_ middleware for that, like `pre('save'))`, and save it back to the database. You can't do it in an update for the reasons explained.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the `$size` thing. I'm doing a `SourceModel.find({treeId: treeId}, '-objects -people -events', callback)` at the moment. Where do I add `$size` in there to return the size of the `objects`, `people` and `events` arrays?

Comment: @Justin808 it's going to have to be a separate (aggregation) query. See the link in my previous comment. If your arrays aren't huge, I would seriously consider just pulling them in to determine their size. Depending on the exact situation, you may be able to get it working with update actions; see my edit.

Answer (score 17):

You can do smthng like that ->

```
source.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    console.log('------------->>>>>> findOneAndUpdate: ');
    this._update.$set.objects = [];
    this._update.$set.people = [];
    this._update.$set.events =  [];
    next();
});
```

pay attention to _update.$set because in the context "this" will be a query. So you can easily add anything you want!

Comment: I have seen similar answers to this on other questions but is this actually supported or just a hack?

Comment: @T.Okahara looks like directly accessing `_update` might be a bit hacky but in the current API there's Query.prototype.getUpdate and [Query.prototype.setUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-setUpdate) which looks like a supported way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I used the updateOne method and was also going to use the updateOne pre hook to make intermittent update before saving to the database. couldn't find a way for it to work. I ended up using the findOneAndUpdate pre hook and doing the updateOne in it.

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next){ 
     const schema = this;
     const { newUpdate } = schema.getUpdate();
     const queryConditions = schema._condition

     if(newUpdate){
       //some mutation magic
       await schema.updateOne(queryConditions, {newUpdate:"modified data"}); 
       next()
     }
     next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the official MongoDB documentation on middleware. They explain why "this" does not refer to the document itself. You may try something in that sense:

```
   source.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next) {
     const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getFilter());
        //modify the appropriate objects
     docToUpdate.save(function(err) {
       if(!err) {
         console.log("Document Updated");
        }
     });
    console.log(docToUpdate); 
     // The document that `findOneAndUpdate()` will modify
       next();   
     });
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that this.getQuery() is deprecated in favor of this.getFilter().

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SCHEMA.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
   this._update.yourNestedElement
   next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    schema.pre(['findOneAndUpdate'], async function(next) {
        try {
            const type = this.get('type')
            const query = this.getQuery()

            const doc =  await this.findOne(query)

            if (type) {
                this.set('type', doc.type)
            }

            next()
        } catch (e) {
            next(new BaseError(e))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose Documentation:

> *You cannot access the document being updated in pre('updateOne') or pre('findOneAndUpdate') query middleware. If you need to access the
> document that will be updated, you need to execute an explicit query
> for the document.*

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
  console.log(docToUpdate); // The document that `findOneAndUpdate()` will modify
});
```