# How to automate demoralization of data (array counts) with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
var thing = new Schema({
  myId: { type: String, required: true },
  objects: [objectSchema],
  objectCount: Number
});
```

I have an API call that returns a list of things. That listing doesn't need the fill list of objects, only the count.

```
var sourceList = function (req, res) {
  return SourceModel.find({}, '-objects', function (err, people) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(people);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
};

var sourceGet = function (req, res) {
  return SourceModel.findOne({myId: req.params.id}, function (err, person) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(person);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
};

exports.initialize = function (app) {
  app.get('/api/thing', thingList);
  app.get('/api/thing/:id', thingGet);
};
```

When adding things to the database I'm reading a datafile uploaded by the user and am upserting into the database with this

```
Thing.findOneAndUpdate({myId: thing.id}, thing, {upsert: true}, callback);
```

I would like Mongoose to keep track of the count for me so, logically, I think of a pre hook, but they are not [overly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823820) [useful](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) without access to the document or at lease the fields/values being updated.

I could do a `find` to check if the document is there and then do a `save` or `update` this would let me use the `save` pre hook as it *dose* have access to the document but that still leaves the `update` which does not.

How do I have mongoose *automatically* keep track of array counts for me or if not stored how do I have mongoose return a full list of documents with a calculated count without returning the full array?

I don't want to have to keep track of the array size manually, thats part of what an ODM should be doing for me.